# DSE Can't Install Graph From LCM

Tags: datastax, datastax-enterprise, datastax-enterprise-graph, datastax-startup

I've installed fresh version of DSE 6.8 for dev purposes, after installing a cluster with one node (Cassandra + Solr) I want to allow Graph, the job keeps failing with error:

`Graph is enabled and should have native-transport-address set to 0.0.0.0. name="node1" ssh-management-address="IP" rack="rack1"`

Changed the cassandra.yaml from:
native_transport_address: IP

to:
native_transport_address: localhost

The job keeps failing, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it says, you need to configure setting `native_transport_address` in the node definition dialog to `0.0.0.0`, and `native_transport_broadcast_address` to actual IP address.

This change should be done in the LCM UI as [described in documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/opscenter/6.7/opsc/LCM/opscLCMeditNode.html), and then you can say reconfigure, or reinstall - you shouldn't change `cassandra.yaml` directly - it's generated by LCM.

Comment: Missed the dialog option. it worked but now I got another error: {
  "stderr": "Job for dse.service failed because the control process exited with error code.\nSee \"systemctl status dse.service\" and \"journalctl -xe\" for details.",
  "return_code": 1
}

Comment: It was memory and native_transport_broadcast_address, updated to the public IP and now everything is working, thank you!